# Manually change weights of Keras convolutional layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, convolution

There is a way to change manually the weights for the tf.layers.Conv2d (https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.15/api_docs/python/tf/layers/Conv2D)? Because this class takes in only the input, the number of kernels to use, etc... and the weights are automatically stored and computed by Tensorflow, but I would a way (like in tf.nn.conv2d - https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/conv2d) to pass directly the weights to the class.

Anyone have a suggestion?

Maybe one could be to load and change manually the value for the variable associate at that layer? I found this solution very bad but it could work.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Let's say you have a basic convolutional neural network like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=(3, 3), 
                           strides=(1, 1), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3, 3), 
                           strides=(1, 1), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(5e-1),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')
])
```

All the convolutional layers will, by default, have the name `'conv2d...'` something.

```
list(map(lambda x: x.name, model.layers))
```

```
['conv2d_19',
 'max_pooling2d_19',
 'conv2d_20',
 'max_pooling2d_20',
 'flatten_8',
 'dense_16',
 'dropout_8',
 'dense_17']
```

Using that, you can iterate through all the convolutional layers.

```
for layer in filter(lambda x: 'conv2d' in x.name, model.layers):
    print(layer)
```

```
<tensorflow.python.keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x00000295BE4EB048>
<tensorflow.python.keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x00000295C1617448>
```

For all these layers, you can obtain the weights shape, and the bias shape.

```
for layer in filter(lambda x: 'conv' in x.name, model.layers):
    weights_shape, bias_shape = map(lambda x: x.shape, layer.get_weights())
```

Then you can use `layer.set_weights()` with the values you want, since you know the correct shape. Let's say `0.12345`. Let's do that with `np.full`, which fills an array of the specified shape with any value you want.

```
for layer in filter(lambda x: 'conv2d' in x.name, model.layers):
    weights_shape, bias_shape = map(lambda x: x.shape, layer.get_weights())
    layer.set_weights([np.full(weights_shape, 0.12345),
                       np.full(bias_shape,    0.12345)])
```

The weights now:

```
[array([[[[0.12345, 0.12345, 0.12345, ..., 0.12345, 0.12345, 0.12345],
          [0.12345, 0.12345, 0.12345, ..., 0.12345, 0.12345, 0.12345],
          [0.12345, 0.12345, 0.12345, ..., 0.12345, 0.12345, 0.12345],
          ...,
          [0.12345, 0.12345, 0.12345, ..., 0.12345, 0.12345, 0.12345],
          [0.12345, 0.12345, 0.12345, ..., 0.12345, 0.12345, 0.12345],
          [0.12345, 0.12345, 0.12345, ..., 0.12345, 0.12345, 0.12345]]]],
       dtype=float32),
 array([0.12345, 0.12345, 0.12345, 0.12345, 0.12345, 0.12345, 0.12345,
        0.12345, 0.12345, 0.12345, 0.12345, 0.12345, 0.12345, 0.12345,
        0.12345, 0.12345, 0.12345, 0.12345, 0.12345, 0.12345, 0.12345,
        0.12345, 0.12345, 0.12345, 0.12345, 0.12345, 0.12345, 0.12345,
        0.12345, 0.12345, 0.12345, 0.12345], dtype=float32)]
```

Fully copy/pastable example:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=(3, 3), 
                           strides=(1, 1), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3, 3), 
                           strides=(1, 1), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(5e-1),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')
])

model.build(input_shape=(None, 28, 28, 1))

for layer in filter(lambda x: 'conv2d' in x.name, model.layers):
    weights_shape, bias_shape = map(lambda x: x.shape, layer.get_weights())
    layer.set_weights([np.full(weights_shape, 0.12345),
                       np.full(bias_shape,    0.12345)])
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Nicholas for the suggestion.

I'm not using Keras for the network modelling, I need in fact to use Tensorflow directly, in particular with [tf-slim](https://github.com/google-research/tf-slim) library.

The solution that you proposed could work for replacing the weights, but the problem to overcome so is that I need also to change how these weights are used to compute the convolution operation. To be more concrete I want to pass to the Conv layer a vector of weights that is representative in some way of the previous weights matrix, so before making the convolution I need to reconstruct a matrix and pass it to the layer.

Any suggestion to accomplish this?

Thank you.